# Is there a better way to show another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Whenever I need to show another Form, I always **instantiate** a new Form Object to **show** another Form (then hiding the current form).

```
/*Code in Form1*/

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

After I instantiated and showed the second Form, I want to **dispose** the previous form (to free up some memory usage) but it is **not working** on the **main** context form.

> However, the Dispose() method is working on other WinForms which is
>   not the main context form.

```
/*Code in Form2*/

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.Show();

    this.Dispose();
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate a Form Object **once only**, then eventually to **call/show it whenever I need it**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your own `ApplicationContext`, and pass that to every form you want to make the `MainForm`. You shouldn't keep forms in memory and open and close them at will in my opinion. This could lead to potential memory leaks.

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ApplicationContext();
ac.MainForm = new Form1(ac);
Application.Run(ac);
```

(You will put this in the place of `Application.Run(new Form1());`)

In `Form1`, when you want to make `Form2` the main form:

```
ac.MainForm = new Form2(ac);
this.Close();
```

This way, the form can be disposed (since you called `Close()` and used `Show` it will automatically dispose) and memory can be cleared. The instance of `Form2` will be the new main form.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Code in Form1*/
Form2 frm2;   // --> Inside the class
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frm2 == null)frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

.

```
/*Code in Form2*/
Form1 frm1;

//Constructor
public Form2(Form1 frm)
{
     frm1= frm;
     InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class called "FormHandler"

this may have a method like

here some prototype code (not tested)

```
public static class FormHandler
{
   private static readonly Dictionary<string,Form> Instances = new Dictionary<string,Form>();

   public TForm CreateFrom<TForm>()
   {
      string typeName = typeof(TForm).FullName;

     if(Instances.ContainsKey(typeName))
     {
          return Instances[typeName]
     }
     else
     {
       // Create Instace with Activator.CreateInstance,
       // and bind the dispose event to remove the form from the collection 
       // on dispose . Also make sure that you unbind the dispose Event
       [...]
      }
}
```

Now the buttonClick would just call

```
FormHandler.CreateForm<Form2>().Show();
```

with seperating the code to a new class you can avoid copy and paste in all buttons